# What about task lists and other web parts in Sharepoint?

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, panel, web-parts

I have the Ajax working on a custom web part written in Visual Studio and it works fine.

Question: I created a task list on the site and added it as a web part to the default page.

I would like that web part (task list) to also refresh asynchronously. I have opened it in Sharepoint designer, but I really don't know how to apply Ajax to it. Any suggestions, pointers towards blogs, demos, etc would be really appreciated.

I'm going to have to add a refresh button so it has a child control to trigger the refresh, which is fine. I just don't know how to get started.

Thanks.